# How to scrape elements within ::beofre selector using bs4 and requests?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

contents withn ::before and ::after tags are not visible when i scrape the preceding div tag using bs4.
how can i scrape them?
I need the value of pageviews from the website.
[i need to scrape data from this website](https://pageviews.toolforge.org/?project=de.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&agent=user&redirects=0&range=all-time&pages=Michael_ten_Hompel)

parser -'lxml'

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import lxml
import re

website_base="https://pageviews.toolforge.org  /?project=de.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&agent=user&redirects=0& range=all-time&pages="
name="Michael_ten_Hompel"
main_url=website_base+name

page=requests.get(main_url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')



req=soup.find('div',{'class':"chart-legend col-lg-12 clearfix"})

print(req)
```

Comment: Its Dynamic content so try out with selenium it will work!

Comment: @BhavyaParikh no need for selenium.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the endpoint to get all the data, dump that to a dataframe and then plot it.

Here's how:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import requests

endpoint = "https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/per-article/" \
           "de.wikipedia/all-access/user/Michael_ten_Hompel/daily/2015070100/2021052100"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) "
                  "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 "
                  "YaBrowser/21.3.0.740 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
}
response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[item["timestamp"], item["views"]] for item in response["items"]],
    columns=["Timestamp", "Value"],
)

plt.plot(df["Timestamp"], df["Value"])
plt.show()
```

This should produce a plot that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hey @baduker just for knowledge purpose how did you get that endpoint can you explain or share some post on it!

Comment: I've used my browser's developer tool. Look under Network -> XHR tab, @BhavyaParikh

Comment: Okay i got your point but user wants this in his anwer??

Comment: The user wanted the data from the page. And the data is the plot. You don't have to plot it like it's on the page but you can use the data, which is the `df` in the code.